# What's the simplest Common Lisp idiom for queued execution of function calls?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

For instance, if I have a database, and the client code queries the database in a rather uniform fashion (through a wrapper macro), how would I go about putting the queries in a queue so that the queries are executed in order, the next running after the last has completed.

This is for an experimental quick-workaround for cl-mongo to see if it fixes issues with parallel requests.

Comment: I ended up using sb-thread/sb-concurrency, although I was in fact looking for a working example initially. This page, http://mihai.bazon.net/blog/howto-multi-threaded-tcp-server-in-common-lisp, although dated, provided useful insights for me to implement a working set of functions. Also, I'd like to note that queueing the requests did solve my issues with cl-mongo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, as the Common Lisp standard doesn't specify any threading capabilities this question doesn't make sense :) However, if you're using threads in your code you may use any of the implementation-independent queue module. The default choice would probably be [lparallel](http://lparallel.org/api/queues/). You can also use some queue provided by your implementation (many do). For instance, SBCL's [sb-concurrency:queue](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Queue) is very simple and straightforward to use.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a simple lock might help you.  It would be a straightforward use case for `bordeaux-threads:with-lock-held`.